# How to pass a value to webview_flutter 4 ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(_posUrl))

Tags: flutter

How can I pass a value to `webview_flutter`'s `loadRequest()` function?

I'm attempting to use `initialUrl` to pass to `webview_flutter`'s `loadRequest()` function, but I'm getting the error message:

```
The instance member '_posUrl' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

Here is my current code:

```
var _posUrl;

  _POSwebviewtState(this._posUrl);

  WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {
          log("New $url");
        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.twitter.com/')) {
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(_posUrl));
```

How can I properly pass a value to `loadRequest()` without encountering this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the controller as late:

```
late WebViewController controller = WebViewController()...;
```

That will make it not being initialised upon object creation, but when it's gonna be accessed for the first time - which is gonna be after `_posUrl` has been initialised and available.