# Is it possible to concatenate strings and variables in a Flutter 3 WebView URL?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, uri

I am creating a WebView page using Flutter 3, and I'm using webview_flutter: 4.2.2. The URL I'm using contains multiple parameters, so I need to use a dynamic URL. I've tried something like the following example, but there's an error in the loadRequest(Uri.parse(urlfull)) part.

Here's the complete code:
import 'dart:html';

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../config.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeTab({super.key});
  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _HomeTabState createState() => _HomeTabState();
}

class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {
  late String urlfull;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startLaunching();
    //untuk melakukan refresh tampilan
  }

  startLaunching() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final authUserId = prefs.getString("auth_user_id")!;
    String username = prefs.getString("username")!;
    final urlfull = baseUrl + "mobile/index?q=$authUserId&u=$username";
    setState(() {});
  }

  WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
      onProgress: (int progress) {},
      onPageStarted: (String url) {},
      onPageFinished: (String url) {},
      onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
    ))
    ..enableZoom(false)
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(urlfull));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
        ));
  }
}
```

I have tried editing in several ways in the loadRequest(Uri.parse(urlfull)) part, but it always displays "Extract Method".

Comment: In your build before returning MaterialApp, can you do debugPrint(urlfull.toString()); just to check if the value is being set correctly before building? And then check if the url is working manually

Comment: There is no issue with the value of urlfull, the problem is that the variable "urlfull" cannot be placed in uri.parse(urlfull), the "Extract Method" message always appears in the Visual Code editor.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have two variables named urlfull.  Within startLaunching you should probably remove "final" before urlfull so that you are updating your state variable urlfull instead of a new urlfull variable.

If you add dev_dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file for [lint](https://pub.dev/packages/lint) and [flutter_lints](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints) your IDE will highlight potential errors like this one.

Comment: I have removed the "final" from urlfull, but the "extract method" message keeps appearing in Visual Code.

Comment: Thank you, I have just found the answer in another post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485252/how-to-pass-a-value-to-webview-flutter-4-loadrequesturi-parse-posurl